# Using CSS only, can a footer be placed at bottom of page but is not "sticky" for mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, mobile-website, mobilewebforms

If a footer is to be placed on a mobile device that supports CSS2.1 and most CSS3 (say, if it is Chrome or Safari on iPhone 4 or iPhone 5S), then can this footer be placed at the bottom of the page, and is NOT sticky, without using any JavaScript?

**One important note is that, we don't want to have a large region of space, and require the user to swipe down to see the footer, because the users can claim that they never knew there was a footer due to the space showing at the bottom of the page and it seemed like end of page already (and therefore they never saw the disclaimer etc for legal issues).**

For example, if we style it for iPhone 4:

if you want to play with it in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ne679/1

[image]

All looks good, with the region above the footer using a CSS `min-height` of `400px`.

However, this page will look on the iPhone 5S as:

[image]

so there is extra space near the bottom of the page.  We can for sure use CSS `position: fixed; bottom: 0` to place it at the bottom of the page for both iPhone 4S and iPhone 5, but then the footer is sticky and will cover up part of the page if the main content actually go beyond the footer at the bottom, which is not a desired behavior.

So without using JavaScript,

1. Is there a known design pattern to make this work? (in Responsive Web Design)
2. Is it true that by using media query, we can style it accordingly depending on the height?  But isn't it true that we have to have a style for each of iPhone 4, iPhone 5S, and if the height of screen is different, say `720px` or something, then again we have to use a media query to style for each height of the possible screen?  That can be troublesome.
3. Even if (2) above can work, what if the page can grow dynamically in height, or if some data is from the database and we never know whether the top part of the page will be short or can be so long that it extend beyond the bottom of screen, in which case we want to naturally just stick the footer right after the end of content, then how can we do that only using CSS but no JavaScript?
4. Complication arises when we style it for iPhone 4 above, because what if some smartphone has a different height, or even when iPhone 4 is in Landscape mode, so the height is not that much -- then we show the top part and the footer is not visible and the users can claim they never saw a footer.

If using JavaScript, then I think the solution can be simple: just don't use `min-height`, but let the footer naturally show on page after main content, and use JavaScript to say, if the bottom `Y` coordinate of the footer is not reaching the bottom `Y` coordinate of the viewport, then simply move footer so that the `Y` coordinate of the footer is the same as the viewport.  Otherwise, just let the footer be where ever displayed after the main content.  But I hope to find a CSS-only solution without JavaScript.

Comment: sure added to http://jsfiddle.net/Ne679/1

Answer (score 1):

use

```
position:absolute; 
bottom:0;
```

EDIT: make the parent position:relative and footer as position:absolute; also you need to add the height of the footer in the bottom-margin of content

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ne679/4/)

Comment: are you saying `position: absolute` relative to the body?  then you have to make the body `height: 100%` and `position: relative` and I don't yet know whether that will work...  what if the content is long and so body of `100%` won't be enough...

Comment: but what if the content is really long, say, if you paste the line `Some log in form or registration form here.` many times so that the content extend beyond the mobile device screen?  I can't make it work yet

Comment: will check more.  it uses CSS `min-height: Calc` so it won't be supported on IE 8 (and partly on IE 9) and I wonder how it will look there

Comment: to avoid using calc you can specify the padding in % rather than 16px.
for example if you have top and bottom padding as 2% rather than 16px you can replace min-height:Calc(100% - 32px) with min-height:96%;

Answer (score 1):

Follow the fantastic CSS only sticky footer as shown in http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

Format HTML as such:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="main"></div>
</div>

<p id="footer"></p>
```

Wrap your content block in a wrapper block and keep footer block separate.

And add css as such:

```
html, body {height: 100%;}
#wrap {min-height: 100%;}
#main {overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 60px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -60px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 60px;
    clear:both;}
```

Here's a demo fiddle for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/sunrays/8jkVj/

**Edit:** Spelling

Comment: It's supposed to be sticky only if the page doesn't need to be scrolled (i.e. small content). Once it starts overflowing, the stickyness should be removed (OP explained it in my answer's comment thread :))

Comment: seems to work in http://jsfiddle.net/8jkVj/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/8jkVj/2/ but it requires adding more structure to the markup?  I suppose there is no simpler solution either.  I might not be able to alter the markup... was hoping only to do it by CSS without altering the markup

Answer (score 0):

You could try `vertical-align: bottom` or `position: relative; bottom: 0`

Comment: don't think so... `vertical-align` is for inline or tablecell elements... and `position: relative` can't do what is expected either

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, if you fix the footer in place, the last bit of the actual content is covered up because the page will not scroll any further?

Add the following CSS to your content div:

```
#myContentDiv {
    margin-bottom : 250px; /* should be equal to the footer's height! I prefer slightly higher (looks nicer). */
}
```

This makes sure that your document is "longer", by adding empty space after the content. This should allow for your page to be scrolled to a point where the content can be viewed in full.

**EDIT**

The above is apparently incorrect (see comment thread below). If you want to actively measure the height of the content box, you'll need javascript as far as I'm aware.

However, there might be a workaround. Not sure if it's valid for you.

Wrap your 3 elements in a container. For clarification:

```
#container
   #header
   #content
   #footer
```

Set #container's `min-height` to the viewport height. That means it will *at the very least* cover the screen, but could be bigger if your content is large.

Fix your #header to the top border of your container. It will always be there, and it will go away if you scroll.

Fix your #footer to the bottom **of the #container**, not the window. Since the container will be at least as big as the screen, that means your footer will either be at the exact bottom, or below the visible part of the page (before scrolling).

Set your #content div to take up any remaining space inbetween the #header and #footer. If your content is tiny, there will be a lot of whitspace between the #content and #footer. If the #content is larger than the screen, the #footer will follow the #content directly.

Is this an acceptable solution/workaround?

**Edit2** If you don't have a header, the same principle applies :)

Comment: no, the requirement is the footer is NOT to be sticky, because it is not good to have the footer cover up precious real estate of the limited screen

Comment: `we don't want to have a large region of space, and require the user to swipe down to see the footer` => This implies that the footer is supposed to be visible without having to scroll. i.e. it is placed at a point where it's in view, even if the content is longer.

Comment: it should show initially unless the page content is taller than the screen, in which case it will show after the long content.  But the footer should never be sticky

Comment: so, basically, it should follow the end of the content block, without overlapping? That's how it works by default (assuming both are divs). Or am I missing something in your question? If I am, I apologize.

Comment: if the content is just 20px tall, then the footer still needs to be near the bottom of the screen

Comment: This requires *something* to measure the height of that box. As far as I'm aware, this is via JavaScript/jQuery, not CSS. There may be a second way. I'll add it to the question now. Not sure if it helps you.